# Different format in output console vs. saved file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find sentiment analysis of a statement. I found the code online and tested it and it worked, but I'm having difficulty to save this output to a text file.

```
# import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer class
# from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment module.

import requests
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

def sentiment_scores(sentence):

    sid_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    sentiment_dict = sid_obj.polarity_scores(sentence)

    with open("file30_12_19.txt", "a+") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(sentiment_dict))
        neg = "sentence was rated as ", sentiment_dict['neg'] * 100, "% Negative"
        neu = "sentence was rated as ", sentiment_dict['neu'] * 100, "% Neutral"
        pos = "sentence was rated as ", sentiment_dict['pos'] * 100, "% Positive"
        allover = "Sentence Overall Rated As "
        text_file.write(str(neg)+str(neu)+str(pos)+str(allover))
        print(str(neg)+str(neu)+str(pos)+str(allover))

        if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05:
            text_file.write("Positive")
            print("Positive")

        elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05:
            text_file.write("Negative")
            print("Negative")

        else:
            text_file.write("Neutral")
            print("Neutral")

        text_file.write("\n")
        text_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sentence1 = [
        "Started off as the greatest series of all time, but had the worst ending of all time.",
        "Exquisite. 'Big Little Lies' takes us to an incredible journey with its emotional and intriguing storyline.",
        "I love Brooklyn 99 so much. It has the best crew ever!!",
        "The Big Bang Theory and to me it's one of the best written sitcoms currently on network TV.",
        "'Friends' is simply the best series ever aired. The acting is amazing.",
        "SUITS is smart, sassy, clever, sophisticated, timely and immensely entertaining!",
        "Cumberbatch is a fantastic choice for Sherlock Holmes-he is physically right (he fits the traditional reading of the character) and he is a damn good actor",
        "What sounds like a typical agent hunting serial killer, surprises with great characters, surprising turning points and amazing cast."
        "This is one of the most magical things I have ever had the fortune of viewing.",
        "I don't recommend watching this at all!"
    ]

    with open("file30_12_19.txt", "a+") as text:
        for data in sentence1:
            text.write(data)
            print(data)
            sentiment_scores(data)
            print("\n")
            text.write("\n")
```

The output I'm getting in the console:

[image]

vs. output in a saved file:

[image]

as you can see, the console output is like statement followed by its analysis data, while in the saved file the all analysis data is showed first followed by all statements, not one by one.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Totally unrelated but you may want to learn about string formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the same file twice and don't flush the buffer in the meantime, so the inner write (in `sentiment_scores`) saves first. Do two smaller `with` statements inside `for data in sentence1:` for the more correct code (keep context manager's scope to the minimum! only when you need it!), or add `text.flush()` before executing the `sentiment_scores`.

```
    for data in sentence1:
        with open("file30_12_19.txt", "a+") as text:
            text.write(data)
            print(data)
        sentiment_scores(data)
        with open("file30_12_19.txt", "a+") as text:
            print("\n")
            text.write("\n")
```

or:

```
    with open("file30_12_19.txt", "a+") as text:
        for data in sentence1:
            text.write(data)
            text.flush()
            print(data)
            sentiment_scores(data)
            print("\n")
            text.write("\n")
            text.flush()
```

Comment: it was the buffer cache that was causing the problem...flush worked....thanks